# Google Marker animation change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, animation, resize

It there a way to add another animation on Marker which is different than DROP and BOUNCE. I would like to enlarge the marker. Thanks in advance!

`<Marker
     position={position}
     animation={window.google.maps.Animation.DROP}
/>`

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question of which language you're using?

Comment: I am using React.js. (react-google-maps)

Comment: You can also use setTimeout(); here is the link https://codesandbox.io/s/9jmkp4on4o

Comment: This example shows still BOUNCE animation which I would like to avoid and enlarge the icon instead.

Comment: Google Maps marker animations are only [bounce and drop](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker#Animation). If you want to enlarge a marker at runtime, you can use custom Icons instead(a small and a big one). Then use setTimeout between them. Here's a [sample  JavaScript fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oy3v4dxb/)

Comment: Thank you! That is what I did and it worked! :)))

Answer (score 0):

Since my comment seems to resolve your issue, I'll post this as answer so that others can also see that your question already had a resolution and might help them in the future. Here's the answer:

Google Maps marker animations are only [bounce and drop](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker#Animation). If you want to enlarge a marker at runtime, you can use custom Icons instead(a small and a big one). Then use setTimeout between them. Here's a [sample JavaScript fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oy3v4dxb/).

```
function initMap() {
  var myLatLng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 4,
    center: myLatLng
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  icon: 'http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_orange.png',
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    title: 'Hello World!'
  });

  setTimeout(function(){ marker.setIcon("http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/orange-blank.png") }, 3000);
}
```